# ASP.net and devexpress scheduler, works local, does not work live

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Hi guys I got some code here thats buggin me.
ive managed to create a page and get it working on local host, but when i publish this to go live and nav to the web page it comes up with this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v11.1,
>   Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (E:\web\shafteccom0\htdocs\Calendar\web.config line 44).

Ive tried adding all the references, and i mean all of the dev express ones, including ones i dont even need.

my project is a web project using `visual studio 10, asp.net,C# & .Net version 3.5`

ive also tried changing the .net version to 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0 but no luck.
If you need my code let me know and ill edit this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that the library that your application is looking for does not exist on the server you are deploying it to (or it cannot load it with the variables provided). Does the live server have the VS2010 references installed to it?

Comment: ive added a reference to all dev express components, also copyed the two specific references to my bin folder as suggested on a different forum.

Comment: After you added the files to your bin folder, did you delete the lines in your web.config file and re-add the references to the project that are pointing to the files in the bin folder? That way your project will try to load it from the bin folder rather than the system.

Comment: I tried adding the .dll's to the bin folder earlier in a different project - the form then opens fine without any errors but the components aren't generated fully; there's no styling or background, no images, almost a shell of the components.

Comment: I then tried the form as a fresh project with all dev express .net references included in my references folder before compiling/publishing the project to its own web server - this is the part that has produced the error I've described at the top of the thread. Sorry for not directly answering your question but I'm not too clear  what you mean, hopefully this information might help!

Comment: In your web.config file you'll have a reference to the dll files you are using. When you right click your project in the solution browser, you can "add references". Have you tried to remove the dll's in the web.config file and adding the references that exist in your bin folder? When you load a project on a server, by default it will try to find all the references on the server because that is what the web.config specifies. If you add it and tell the project that it exists in your bin folder it will try to load it from there instead.

Comment: OK, thanks... how do I specify that the dll's are in my bin folder? 

I've currently got refs like the following in my web config's assembly section:

 <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>

& 

<add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>

in httpmodules. If I remove these references what should I replace them with?

Comment: They are automatically re-added when you use the "Add References" option in your solution explorer. Just make sure you get them all.

Comment: well in my solution explorer there all there.

Comment: Right, but have you added the reference to the project? After you deleted the lines out of your web.config. Right click on your solution, hit add reference, click on the browse tab, select the dlls in your bin folder, hit Ok. They will be automatically be loaded into your web.config file.

Comment: yup thats been done, im republishing atm to the server but this time ive set to copy local = true.  i have a feeling what you said is true about the references pointing to the wrong thing.  Ill update you with the results

Comment: worked got rid of the error, unfortunatly ive now got an sql error time out, but i shud be able to solve it. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just making sure:  Are you sure your references set to "CopyLocal"?

I think DevEx installs it's assemblies in the GAC, so your local copy may be working but not when you deploy.  Have you tried looking in the bin on the publish location to see if they are actually there?